# Line Breaking on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I posted a sentence in a single line in my wordpress site and it is showing perfect in laptop but in mobile devices the sentence is breaking into two lines, I want to fix this into one line.

The issue:(Check from the images)

(mobile view)
[image]

(laptop view)

[image]

Comment: We dont check images, we check code, show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, the single line(s) is simply too long for the mobile viewport. At the expense of SEO rating, you *could* try to make the font size smaller to compensate for sentence length. I'm not sure how else you'd tackle guitar tabs in mobile inside what I assume to be a code block.